# How to get a Download link for a document in SharePoint library for anonymous users

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365

I uploaded a file to a folder in

```
https://sitename-my.sharepoint.com/
```

I created a view link, requiring no access

[image]

The link that I get when I click on share looks something like this

> https://somesite-my.sharepoint.com/personal/username/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=ayx%3d&docid=xyz&rev=1

The problem is when I open the generated url in incognito window, it opens in word online

Is there a way to change this make it download file directly?

Is there a api for this just like how onedrive has like below which will directly download the file

https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/s!code/root/content

Comment: Does right-click and save as work for you?

Comment: that will require sign-in I guess, I need a download link for anonymous access

Comment: basically I am using a javascript plugin, which will ask for the source of the document and download it and modify it. I want to get a link to do that

Comment: Can you send the guest-link in an e-mail and right-click from there?

Comment: No, I am not able to do that
I also tried changing href in one of the links here, when I right click and save, it is coming up as a webpage

Comment: THIS IS WHAT MY LINK LOOKS LIKE. HOW DO I CHANGE THAT TO A DOWNLOAD LINK?
https://careficient.sharepoint.com/:p:/g/Eb1nYPOAd1xFp9Wr5Mnr14ABC2Rise_zvBHIPsI-EsOStC

Comment: @Debbie you can reach me @ svignesh@live.com

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the direct download link, you have to click on the document, get the share link which will look like below url

> https://sitename-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xyz/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=xyz%3d&docid=xyz&rev=1

Now all you have to do is replace the **guestacces.aspx** with **download.aspx**, and the url should look like the one below

> https://sitename-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xyz/_layouts/15/download.aspx?guestaccesstoken=xyz%3d&docid=xyz&rev=1

When people click the link the document will automatically start to download

Comment: This worked like a charm!

Comment: In 2021 using SharePoint Online, the URL is not in this form (and does not contain guestaccess.aspx).

Answer (score 13):

You should be able to add the query string parameter `Web=0'

For example:

`https://sitename-my.sharepoint.com/personal/vignesh/Documents/SomePresentation.pptx?Web=0`

Answer (score 5):

Adding `?Web=0` worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest solution:

**Open the file** in Sharepoint, go to **File** -> **Save As** -> **Download a Copy**

After it downloaded to your computer, go to your downloads history (Usually Ctrl+J), then find the most recent downloaded file, and copy the link of the downloaded file (better using Google Chrome).

Easy and fun! =)

Answer (score 1):

There are also column settings that can add or remove the Get Link option. For instance, in the Modify View menu, the column "Name (linked to document with edit menu)" displays the ... option to select the Get Link dialog. The other Name columns do not have this option.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. My share link does not include "guestacces.aspx" and the ?Web=0 query param didn't work. What you can do is share a link, download the pdf from a browser and go to the browser downloads page to copy the link. Ctrl-J on Windows, Cmd-Shift-J I believe on a Mac