# How to get a Download link for a document in SharePoint for anonymous users

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, download

I want a link that I can use for anonymous users to download a document on my SharePoint.
The question has already been answered [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184653/how-to-get-a-download-link-for-a-document-in-sharepoint-library-for-anonymous-us?newreg=36464de418a945f1a8fa58b72406fa1b), however I think the answer is not up to date anymore because the format of the link changed.

Currently, I can generate a link that allows anyone who has the link to edit the file. But the link I get looks something like this:

https://somesite-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/hN90HTQBV3sfeYL1M6JnYDGE6J4RoL61

How do I get the download link from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict the link to be read only, but you cannot get a link to directly download the file for non authenticated users. It will link to the web view of the file:

[image]

Depending on your sharing settings (either tenant level, OneDrive, SharePoint or pr site) anonymous link sharing might be disabled altogether...

Comment: Is there a reason for why this is not possible anymore? 
Also this means, that if I want to download a document from SharePoint I will always need to do some sort of authentication to make it possible, right?

Comment: It would mean you could set up a tenant as a "free" file share. I think it is quite clear why that isn't possible...